# I need a little help with integration

Tags: integration

I'm asked to explain step by step how my teacher integrated this problem(the image is his calculations). Why and how does he pull K down from the power of e and multiplies it instead?

e^x+k becomes k*e^x

[image of his calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFBpY.jpg)

we write K instead of C (constant) in my class. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the caluclations are just plain wrong if you want to keep the same meaning of $\kappa$ throughout. From the line

$$ln(|y|) = ln(|x|) + \kappa$$

If we exponentiate both sides

$$e^{ln(|y|)} = e^{ln(|x|) + \kappa} = e^{ln(|x|)} \cdot  e^{\kappa}$$

so

$$|y| = |x| \cdot e^\kappa$$

Now since $\kappa$ is just a constant, you are perfectly free to redefine it $e^\kappa \rightarrow \kappa$ to get the final line in the calculations. And it seems like that is what has been done (slopily and without explanation) in a couple of lines of the calulctions.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the quick answer, i get it now :)